# Edit model after loading it woth only the .h5 file

Tags: python, tensorflow

It's the first time I'm loading a model when the .h5 file is all I have. This is what I've done right now:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense

new_model = load_model(filepath)

new_model.optimizer

new_model.get_weights()
```

I was wondering is there a way to recreate the train and test data? Are they important to retrive to start edit the saved model or is there another way? Thanks for the help

Comment: Users save the necessary components in .h5 format, such as the activation function, Scheduler, Custom Loss function, etc. but do not train or test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a trained model (no matter the format actually) it's the architecture and weights, the train and test data are not "melted" into the model anyhow and you cannot retrieve it from it.

Comment: Thanks so much. That was my fear. Is there a way to work with it without the data? or right now the file I have is just useless without the dataset?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's useless by no means. It depends what do you want to do with it. You can use it for inference (the forward pass, the prediction, whatever you want to call it) and you can use it for training as let's say "initial" model, so as not to start training from random weights, but start from what you currently have (that's often done when the training takes long time and it's more beneficial to start from a pre-trained model). But as I said you cannot extract neither the training nor the test data from a trained model. It's a black box. INPUT->DO MAGIC and/or ALGEBRA ->OUTPUT :D

Comment: Wait, sorry to bother you again. Considering that right now I've only the .h5 file and no data I can't do any prediction, right?

Comment: You can do prediction using loaded model, you need to feed it some input data though (from any source, but not the training data, since you don't have it as we established).
e.g. if you have an image classifier you have to load an image and feed it to the loaded model, that's it.
Example from docs:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#keras_h5_format